# crate db edge_ngram search analyzer change

Tags: analyzer, crate

I created custom analyzer.

```
 create ANALYZER analyzer_test (TOKENIZER standard,TOKEN_FILTERS (
 asciifolding, 
 lowercase, 
 myedge WITH (type='edge_ngram',min_gram=3,max_gram=20) ));
```

I search in my db for example "**bro**".Results  are like this.

bro

brow

brown

It is okay but, i search "**brow**". Results are same.

bro

brow

brown

But i only want to find start with "**brow**". How can do this.

brow

brown

**Edit :** My custom analyzer has asciifolding . So normallly when I searched "çan", results are listed like this "çan" , "can","çanak" , . But If I use standard analyzer for analyzing the query term, I had another problem. When I searched "çan" no results. In summary, I want something like this. I have to use asciifolding.I want to list of results which are start with "query term". Phrase and phrase_prefix options are not enough for me, beacsue some searching have multi words but not phrase. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, CrateDB uses the same analyzer one defined on column definition to analyze search terms. In case of an `edge_ngram` tokenizer/token_filter this is mostly not what you want (in your case it analyzes the search term into `bro` and `brow` and searches for both of the tokens). A custom search analyzer can be defined by adding options to the `match` predicate, see https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/general/dql/fulltext.html#predicates-match.

Example use of the `standard` analyzer for analyzing the query term:

`select * from my_table where match(my_string, 'brow') using best_fields with(analyzer='standard');`

This should result in the expected matches.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My custom analyzer has asciifolding . So normallly when I  searched "çan", results are listed like this "çan" , "can","çanak" , . But If I use standard analyzer for analyzing the query term, I had another problem. When I searched "çan" no results. In summary, I want something like this. I have to use asciifolding.I want to list of results which are start with "query term". Phrase and phrase_prefix options are not enough for me, beacsue some searching have multi words but not phrase.

Comment: So just create another custom analyzer which is NOT using an edge_ngram token filter and use this for searching.